# How to return parent function value from child

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get a child function to return on behalf of the parent. Is this possible? Here is the pseudo code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
function editUserProfile(){
    uploadFileToS3($file);
    //Save the rest of the edited profile
}

function uploadFileToS3($file){
    if( fileSize($file) + userStorageUsage > userMaxStorage){
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['storage' => 'Storage full']);
    }
    //upload the file
}
```

EDIT:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->child();
}

public function child(){
    if(foo==bar){
        return 'Test';
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to provide some more code. For me at least, I don't think I'd be able to help you from just that snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `return` keyword, like:

```
function editUserProfile(){
    return uploadFileToS3($file);
}
```

Or, if you want to do something before you return the value, then:

```
function editUserProfile(){
    $results = uploadFileToS3($file);
    //Save the rest of the edited profile
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's perfect. Would it be possible to get the return to be ignored without using an if in the parent function?

Comment: @CharlvanStaden you can use an if in the child function instead. If my post answered your question, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Please see my edit. Is that what you had in mind? The parent function still always returns null.

Comment: @CharlvanStaden this means that the if condition is evaluated to false.